# Shockley's Equation for JFET transistor in Proteus

Tags: simulation, proteus, jfet

I'm trying to do a simulation using Proteus for the NJFET Transistor ...
But when simulating the Shockley's Transfer equation i get a wrong curve [image]

And here is graph's properties

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify source 2 as drain current. At the moment, with only Vgate specified, it looks like you are plotting gate current against a base of gate voltage